# Client Side Component not working on Server after refreshing in NUXT

Tags: server, nuxt.js, page-refresh

I am using the [vue-hotel-datepicker6](https://github.com/ZestfulNation/vue-hotel-datepicker) in Nuxt and it is working fine on localhost, but I faced a problem when I deployed the app on the server, It first time load the calendar properly but after refreshing not load the calendar again.
Similar situation I faced with the vue-mapbox.

```html
<client-only>
      <HotelDatePicker
        v-show="!isLoading"
        :startingDateValue="initialStartDate"
        :endingDateValue="initialEndDate"
        :key="calendarKey"
        :alwaysVisible="visibility"
        :showSingleMonth="showSingleMonth"
        format="DD-MM-YYYY"
        :periodDates="periodDates"
        :showPrice="true"
        :hoveringTooltip="false"
        priceSymbol="€"
        :disabledDates="disabledDates"
        :halfDay="false"
        :endDate="endDate"
        :disableCheckoutOnCheckin="true"
        @previous-month-rendered="onPreviousMonth"
        @next-month-rendered="onNextMonth"
        @check-in-selected="checkInSelected"
        @check-out-changed="checkOutChange"
      />
    </client-only>
```

Comment: You wrote `vue-hotel-datepicker6`, is the  `6` a typo or some actual hidden version? Could you please share your `nuxt.config.js` file? Where do you host your app? Do you have any issues if you build your app locally? Any DOM mismatch or alike in the console when you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it on the server by using **Static site generation** (aka SSG).
For that, you need to change the `target` from `'server'` to `'static'` and don't forget to run `yarn generate` rather than `yarn build`.

---

You can follow these article for using static site generation:

- https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-take-full-advantage-of-full-static-mode-in-nuxt-2-13/
- https://medium.com/a-man-with-no-server/static-site-generators-nuxt-js-2fa9782d27c8